# Printf - print repeating minus symbols

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, printf

how can I use `printf` to print a row of minus symbols?

when I try: `printf "-----------\\n"`

I get:

```
bash: printf: - : invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

when I try: `printf "\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\\n"`

I get: `\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an extremely in-efficient way to use `printf()` without using format specifiers. You generally define them to let know what type of output is being formatted. It should have been written as

```
printf '%s\n' "-----------"
```

Such that the `printf` matches the `-----------` as a string type with the format specifier that takes a string keyword (`%s`). The `\n` after the specifier means, add the new line after the string is printed.

With the attempt what you have, when the quote removal happens `printf` interprets the dashes as one of its command line flags, which it does *not* understand.

Another hacky way of doing it would be to *let* `printf` know that its command line arguments are complete and interpret the content following it as its arguments. Most of the shell built-ins and/or external commands support this by suffixing a `--` after the command keyword, i.e. as

```
printf -- "-----------\n"
```

Comment: inefficient way of using printf ? so printing something like '---- 1 Jan 2020 ----'+CR have to be formated like this : `printf '%s %s %s\n' '---' "$( date )" '---'` ? i was guessing it is  more `printf '--- %s ---\n' "$( date )"` like in other shell or C like format of printf